# Neo4j upsert with possibly new edge type

Tags: neo4j, cypher, upsert

I am trying to create upsert logic in neo4j. I need to upsert two nodes and connect the two nodes with a relationship.

If there is an existing relationship that shares 3 specific properties, `e1_id`, `e2_id`, and `model`, then I need to completely overwrite that relationship with new data and possibly a new type.

For example, I have tried this:

```
MERGE (snapchat:ORG{name:'ORG_snapchat'})
MERGE (xbox:ORG{name:'ORG_xbox'})

MERGE (xbox)-[edge:{e1_id:'111', e2_id:'222', model:'TEST'}]->(snapchat)
ON CREATE
    SET edge:OPPO{e1_id:'111', e2_id:'222', url:'test.com', date:'2022-09-09', model:'TEST', context:'THIS IS A TEST'}
ON MATCH
    SET edge:OPPO{e1_id:'111', e2_id:'222', url:'test.com', date:'2022-09-09', model:'TEST', context:'THIS IS A TEST'};
```

However, this yields:

```
Invalid input '{': expected an identifier (line 4, column 20 (offset: 150))
"MERGE (xbox)-[edge:{e1_id:'222_xbox_test', e2_id:'111_snapchat_test', model:'TEST'}]->(snapchat)"
```

Because it is expecting me to specify an edge type before it can merge. I'm not sure what to do here.

Should I just write a query that deletes any matching edge and then creates a new edge?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: When doing MERGE, you need to specify the relationship type (OPPO) then you can only SET the properties, not includng OPPO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edge has only exactly a single type. When you create it with MERGE you have to define it. Therefore -

> Should I just write a query that deletes any matching edge and then
> creates a new edge?

Yes, if you can simply delete an existing edge than yes. Do that. Make sure to use an `OPTIONAL MATCH`, so that it works even if there is not existing edge.